# Facebook Like 500 Error in WordPress

Tags: facebook, iframe

I get a series of errors when I click a Like button on my site.

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
>
> POST https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/connect 500 (OK)

And here's the code:

```
<div class="feedback facebook">
    <iframe allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 160px; height: 21px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Not sure what's wrong with my code. I tried urlencoding the URL. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the same, did you find the solution. If yes, please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

your link is apparently doing an HTTP POST to https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/connect, when it ought to doing an HTTP POST to http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/connect.

with that said, your iframe code sample isn't exactly helpful, for the important part is what is returned by the function 'get_permalink()' (Described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

do this:

**Replace**

```
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light"
```

**With**

```
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo str_replace("https","http",get_permalink()); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light"
```

Also ***Review the following*** (as well as the link)

> After July 2013 migration, the Like button required an absolute URL in
>   the href parameter.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#july2013